# How can I hide the source code that overflows a listing's frame?

Tags: listings, boxes, clip

I've two side-by-side listing boxes that compare input and ouput code. How can I tell LaTeX to hide the code that is printed outside the listing boxes?

Here is the LaTeX code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,export]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{
    %numbers=left,numberstyle=\tiny, stepnumber=1, numbersep=5pt,
    breaklines=true,
    breakatwhitespace=false,
    tabsize=2,
    basicstyle=\footnotesize,%\ttfamily,
    frame=single,
    rulecolor=\color{gray}
}
\usepackage{adjustbox}

\begin{document}

\noindent\begin{minipage}{.45\textwidth}
    \begin{lstlisting}[caption=code 1,frame=tlrb,breaklines=false]{Name}
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <s:Body>
    <GetSpecialtiesResponse xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
    <GetSpecialtiesResult xmlns:a="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/WsAgenda.DataContracts" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <a:Specialty>
        <a:code>cardiology</a:code>
        <a:name>Cardiologie</a:name>
    </a:Specialty>
    <a:Specialty>
        <a:code>neurology</a:code>
        <a:name>Neurologie</a:name>
    </a:Specialty>
    <a:Specialty>
        <a:code>urology</a:code>
        <a:name>Urologie</a:name>
    </a:Specialty>
    <a:Specialty>
        <a:code>physiotherapy</a:code>
        <a:name>Physiotherapie</a:name>
    </a:Specialty>
    </GetSpecialtiesResult>
    </GetSpecialtiesResponse>
    </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
    \end{lstlisting}
\end{minipage}\hfill
\begin{minipage}{.45\textwidth}
    \begin{lstlisting}[caption=code 2,frame=tlrb,breaklines=true]{Name}
{"Specialties": [
    {
    "id": "cardiology",
    "description": "Cardiologie"
    },
    {
    "id": "neurology",
    "description": "Neurologie"
    },
    {
    "id": "urology",
    "description": "Urologie"
    },
    {
    "id": "physiotherapy",
    "description": "Physiotherapie"
    }
]}
    \end{lstlisting}
\end{minipage}  

\end{document}
```

And here is the PDF result:

[image]

Comment: Hi, welcome. Please give a full compileable code.

Comment: @AndréC: Done. Sorry :)

Comment: `breaklines=false` makes no sense here. Use `=true`

Comment: If I understand correctly, you want the text on the left listing to be cut so that it is not written outside the box. You do not want this text to be written on the line. Is that it?

Comment: @user187802 no breaklines makes sense to me... I don't want breaklines since a complete view of the code is not necessary and it will make my listing longer and less readable. What i would like is to simply hide text that goes beyond the frame of the listing

Comment: @AndréC You 're right

Comment: A solution might be to allow for linebreaks, and tweak the package with `\makeatletter ... \makeatother` to override the `postbreak` option. At every new line created by `breaklines=true`, output nothing instead of the rest of the line. However, I don't know what the syntax would look like exactly...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a version using the `viewport` option that package `adjustbox` provides for its box commands. The code had to be rearranged a bit such that the frame around the listings is added by `\adjustbox` and the captions by `\captionof`. Otherwise you would get a missing right side of the frame.

Everything was wrapped into a new environment `codebox` which takes the box width as its first and the listing's caption as its second parameter. It's basically just a sketch of the idea; a better interface for more customization could be added by providing a key-value option list for the environment.

Full example code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,export]{report}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{adjustbox}

\lstset{
    %numbers=left,numberstyle=\tiny, stepnumber=1, numbersep=5pt,
    breaklines=true,
    breakatwhitespace=false,
    tabsize=2,
    basicstyle=\footnotesize,%\ttfamily,
%    frame=single,
%    rulecolor=\color{gray}
}

\newenvironment{codebox}[2]{%
    \begin{minipage}[t]{#1}%
    \vspace*{-0.5\baselineskip}
    \captionof{lstlisting}{#2}\par
    \vspace*{-0.7\baselineskip}
    \begin{adjustbox}{
        cfbox=gray,
        clip=true,
        viewport={\fboxrule+\fboxsep} {-\depth} {\linewidth-\fboxrule-\fboxsep} {\height}
    }%
    \hbadness=100
    \hfuzz=\maxdimen
}{%
    \end{adjustbox}%
    \end{minipage}%
}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]

\noindent
\begin{codebox}{0.48\textwidth}{Code 1}
    \begin{lstlisting}[breaklines=false]
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <s:Body>
    <GetSpecialtiesResponse xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
    <GetSpecialtiesResult xmlns:a="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/WsAgenda.DataContracts" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <a:Specialty>
        <a:code>cardiology</a:code>
        <a:name>Cardiologie</a:name>
    </a:Specialty>
    <a:Specialty>
        <a:code>neurology</a:code>
        <a:name>Neurologie</a:name>
    </a:Specialty>
    <a:Specialty>
        <a:code>urology</a:code>
        <a:name>Urologie</a:name>
    </a:Specialty>
    <a:Specialty>
        <a:code>physiotherapy</a:code>
        <a:name>Physiotherapie</a:name>
    </a:Specialty>
    </GetSpecialtiesResult>
    </GetSpecialtiesResponse>
    </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
    \end{lstlisting}
\end{codebox}
\hfill
\begin{codebox}{.48\textwidth}{Code 2}
    \begin{lstlisting}[breaklines=true]
{"Specialties": [
    {
    "id": "cardiology",
    "description": "Cardiologie"
    },
    {
    "id": "neurology",
    "description": "Neurologie"
    },
    {
    "id": "urology",
    "description": "Urologie"
    },
    {
    "id": "physiotherapy",
    "description": "Physiotherapie"
    }
]}
    \end{lstlisting}
\end{codebox}
\medskip

\lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```

outputs

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Well,
By now the only way i found to achieve what i want is to remove the overflowing code in the tex source. It's not an elegant solution but it solves the problem:

```
\noindent\begin{minipage}[t]{.52\textwidth}
    \begin{lstlisting}[caption=Réponse SOAP du web service agenda à la demande de la liste des spécialités,label={lst:getspecSOAP},frame=tlrb,breaklines=false]
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.
<s:Body>
<GetSpecialtiesResponse xmlns="http:
<GetSpecialtiesResult xmlns:a="http:
    <a:Specialty>
        <a:code>cardiology</a:code>
        <a:name>Cardiologie</a:name>
    </a:Specialty>
    <a:Specialty>
        <a:code>neurology</a:code>
        <a:name>Neurologie</a:name>
    </a:Specialty>
    <a:Specialty>
        <a:code>urology</a:code>
        <a:name>Urologie</a:name>
    </a:Specialty>
    <a:Specialty>
        <a:code>physiotherapy</a:code>
        <a:name>Physiotherapie</a:name>
    </a:Specialty>
</GetSpecialtiesResult>
</GetSpecialtiesResponse>
</s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
    \end{lstlisting}
\end{minipage}\hfill
\begin{minipage}[t]{.45\textwidth}
    \begin{lstlisting}[caption=Réponse JSon produite par le datamapper,label={lst:getspecREST},frame=tlrb,breaklines=true]
{"Specialties": [
    {
    "id": "cardiology",
    "description": "Cardiologie"
    },
    {
    "id": "neurology",
    "description": "Neurologie"
    },
    {
    "id": "urology",
    "description": "Urologie"
    },
    {
    "id": "physiotherapy",
    "description": "Physiotherapie"
    }
]}
    \end{lstlisting}
\end{minipage}
```

And the result is:

[image]